# Tensorflow Keras RMSE metric returns different results than my own built RMSE loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, loss-function

This is a regression problem

My custom RMSE loss:

```
def root_mean_squared_error_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.keras.backend.sqrt(tf.keras.losses.MSE(y_true, y_pred))
```

Training code sample, where create_model returns a dense fully connected sequential model

```
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import RootMeanSquaredError
model = create_model()
model.compile(loss=root_mean_squared_error_loss, optimizer='adam', metrics=[RootMeanSquaredError()])

model.fit(train_.values,
          targets,
          validation_split=0.1,
          verbose=1,
          batch_size=32)
```

```
Train on 3478 samples, validate on 387 samples
Epoch 1/100
3478/3478 [==============================] - 2s 544us/sample - loss: 1.1983 - root_mean_squared_error: 0.7294 - val_loss: 0.7372 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 0.1274
Epoch 2/100
3478/3478 [==============================] - 1s 199us/sample - loss: 0.8371 - root_mean_squared_error: 0.3337 - val_loss: 0.7090 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 0.1288
Epoch 3/100
3478/3478 [==============================] - 1s 187us/sample - loss: 0.7336 - root_mean_squared_error: 0.2468 - val_loss: 0.6366 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 0.1062
Epoch 4/100
3478/3478 [==============================] - 1s 187us/sample - loss: 0.6668 - root_mean_squared_error: 0.2177 - val_loss: 0.5823 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 0.0818
```

I expected both loss and root_mean_squared_error to have same values, why is there a difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two key differences, from [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.2/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py#L2575):

1. `RMSE` is a *stateful* metric (it keeps memory) - yours is stateless
2. Square root is applied [after](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.2/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py#L2579) taking a global mean, not before an `axis=-1` mean like [MSE does](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.2/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py#L1198)

   - As a result of 1, 2 is more involved: mean of a running quantity, `total`, is taken, with respect to another running quantity, `count`; both quantities are reset via [`RMSE.reset_states()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.2/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py#L218).

The raw formula fix is easy - but integrating statefulness will require work, as is beyond the scope of this question; refer to source code to see [how it's done](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.2/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py#L307). A fix for 2 with a comparison, below.

---

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import RootMeanSquaredError as RMSE

def root_mean_squared_error_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.math.squared_difference(y_true, y_pred)))

np.random.seed(0)

#%%###########################################################################
rmse = RMSE(dtype='float64')
rmsel = root_mean_squared_error_loss

x1 = np.random.randn(32, 10)
y1 = np.random.randn(32, 10)
x2 = np.random.randn(32, 10)
y2 = np.random.randn(32, 10)

#%%###########################################################################
print("TensorFlow RMSE:")
print(rmse(x1, y1))
print(rmse(x2, y2))
print("=" * 46)
print(rmse(x1, y1))
print(rmse(x2, y2))

print("\nMy RMSE:")
print(rmsel(x1, y1))
print(rmsel(x2, y2))
```

```py
TensorFlow RMSE:
tf.Tensor(1.4132492562096124, shape=(), dtype=float64)
tf.Tensor(1.3875944990740972, shape=(), dtype=float64)
==============================================
tf.Tensor(1.3961984634354354, shape=(), dtype=float64)  # same inputs, different result
tf.Tensor(1.3875944990740972, shape=(), dtype=float64)  # same inputs, different result

My RMSE:
tf.Tensor(1.4132492562096124, shape=(), dtype=float64)  # first result agrees
tf.Tensor(1.3614563994283353, shape=(), dtype=float64)  # second differs since stateless
```

Comment: both my function and the one you have rewritten results in the same output. As for the state, I have used the 'mse' loss function directly and the result at the end of an epoch is not equal to the square of the RMSE as well. As far as I understand, the metric is evaluated at the end of epoch while loss function at every batch.

Comment: @ma7555 No, our functions don't have the same output - replace mine with yours and run above code. MSE is also a stateless metric, so using it instead doesn't solve your problem. I suggest a class-based approach, tracking `total` and `count` with logic identical to TF's.

Comment: ok so 'mse' is also stateless, meaning that the number that is printed at the end of the epoch is actually the last batch 'mse', still the difference is extremely big. at the end of epoch one these are the numbers: val_loss: 5.6630 - val_root_mean_squared_error: 0.1597

Comment: @ma7555 Values printed at end are averages over the entire epoch, not last batch's. The difference is indeed large, but RMSE works rather unintuitively; can't tell much without seeing the actual model and data (can't use random noise since its loss behavior differs significantly). Regardless, this is a question of its own.